# Special characters in filenames + nginx + php = 404

Tags: debian, nginx, special-characters, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Recently I moved to a new server after the old one had died. I had wordpress installation there, powered by Apache2 and Gentoo Linux. When moving, I decided to use **nginx** and **Debian** instead. I brought my wordpress back to work and everything would be fine if not for one little...

## Problem

Images that contain special characters in the filenames don't load, I get *404 Not Found*. For instance when requesting

```
http://my_site/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Zajęcia-dla-dorosłych-z-bollywood-dance.jpg
```

wordpress responds

```
You tried going to http://my_site/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Zaj%C4%99cia-dla-doros%C5%82ych-z-bollywood-dance.jpg, and it doesn't exist.
```

I played a while with the terminal and discovered that image filenames on the server differ a little bit from those requested by the wordpress. Despite they look identically, special character sequences are encoded in a different way. For example, when I copy filename `Zajęcia-dla-dorosłych-z-bollywood-dance.jpg` from terminal it is encoded as `Zaje&#808;cia-dla-doros&#322;ych-z-bollywood-dance.jpg`. On the other hand, wordpress is looking for file `Zaj&#281;cia-dla-doros&#322;ych-z-bollywood-dance.jpg` which doesn't exist, of course.

Both systems (the old Gentoo and the current Debian) are set to use UTF-8-based locale.

## How to solve?

I think about three possible reasons:

- Debian stores special characters in filenames differently than Gentoo
- my new mysql stores special characters differently than the old one
- nginx handles special characters differently than Apache

Any suggestions how to falsificate those hypothesis and, finally, solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem by correcting the filenames with a [script](https://gist.github.com/f521835cadd376c9d4f1). I think the encoding of special characters was broken at some point when I was copying the files between systems (Gentoo => Mac OS X => Debian). Feel free to use and edit my script it you have similar problem.